# What causes wildfly memcached error and what is the solution?

Tags: server, wildfly-10

> 14:13:54,515 ERROR [stderr] (Memcached IO over {MemcachedConnection to /172.16.0.63:11211 /172.16.0.66:11211 /172.16.0.68:11211}) 2017-10-20 14:13:54.515 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@19f3d5d5
>
> 14:13:54,516 ERROR [stderr] (Memcached IO over {MemcachedConnection to /172.16.0.63:11211 /172.16.0.66:11211 /172.16.0.68:11211}) 2017-10-20 14:13:54.516 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Reconnecting due to failure to connect to {QA sa=/172.16.0.68:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0}
>
> 14:13:54,516 ERROR [stderr] (Memcached IO over {MemcachedConnection to /172.16.0.63:11211 /172.16.0.66:11211 /172.16.0.68:11211}) java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information

Comment: `java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information`

Comment: ERROR [stderr] (Memcached IO over {MemcachedConnection to /172.16.0.63:11211 /172.16.0.66:11211 /172.16.0.68:11211}) java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information

ERROR [stderr] (Memcached IO over {MemcachedConnection to /172.16.0.63:11211 /172.16.0.66:11211 /172.16.0.68:11211})  at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)

ERROR [stderr] (Memcached IO over {MemcachedConnection to /172.16.0.63:11211 /172.16.0.66:11211 /172.16.0.68:11211})  at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)